# highcharts / node-export-server: Blank charts with large data sets

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts Export server: v2.0.24

Running as local server: highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1 --logLevel 4

I have a lot of x-axis data points representing a ping's success status, every minute all day.

If I POST about 15 hours worth of data to be exported as a line chart, the generated chart is correct.

Post data example:

`{"infile":{"time":{"timezone":"Africa/Johannesburg"},"chart":{"type":"line","exporting":{"enabled":false},"width":2000},"title":{"text":"Utilities Availability"},"navigation":{"buttonOptions":{"enabled":false}},"xAxis":{"type":"datetime","dateTimeLabelFormats":{ "millisecond": "%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S", "second": "%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S",  "minute": "%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M", "hour": "%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M", "day": "%Y<br/>%m-%d",  "month": "%Y-%m", "year": "%Y" }},"yAxis":{"allowDecimals":false,"min":0,"tickInterval":1,"title":{"text":"Status"}},"series":[{"name":"/Breede Valley Utility","color":"#2f7ed8","data":[{"x":1574589619091,"y":1},{"x":1574589634425,"y":0},...`

If I send more than 15 hours worth of data, I end up with a blank chart.

I wonder if there is too much data to be plotted on the x axis as the generated chart has a max width of 2000px? I tried to fiddle with width and scale but I am not sure that will solve the issue.

Working chart:
[image: Working chart]

Blank chart:
[image: Blank chart]

On my web version of this chart, both the smaller and larger data sets work fine. I am using x zoom to allow the user to see more details.

[image]

If anyone can suggest something else to try, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might not be related to export server but rather to error #12 (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/12/). In a nutshell, there is a limitation set by default for data which contains points in an object (`{x: xValue, y: yValue}`) format. It is controlled by the `turboThreshold` option (which is set to 1000 in case of line series). Take a look at the example below. Try to set a higher `turboThreshold` (or disable it) and then try to export your chart.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.turboThreshold

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j6pwo0ye/